# Some trouble with Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I try to get some data from my account Google Analytics to display it on dashboard.

I have already tried two path:

*PHP quickstart for web applications*

By instructions on [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php)

I create app, downloaded client-secrets.json, install google/apiclient:^2.0 by composer and add exapmple files - try_google.php and oauth2callback.php.

try_google.php:

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  $response = getReport($analytics);

  // Print the response.
  printResults($response);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "228691701";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}

/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Which results in the following error:

> "Ошибка 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9egD.png]

## second option

I follow all this instruction [Получаем данные Google Analytics из PHP](https://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/poluchaem-dannye-google-analytics-iz-php),

my google.php file is:

```
<?php
  include 'functions.php';
  require_once('libs/google/Google_Client.php');
  require_once('libs/google/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php');
  
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('My cool application');
  
  $client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      // тот самый email, который мы добавляли в analytics
      'quickstart@riddlesbest.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
      // полный путь к загруженному секретному ключу

      file_get_contents('./libs/google/keys/riddlesbest-ce193de84be7.p12')
    )
  );
  
  // Client ID со страницы API Access
  $client->setClientId('729918328491-k9bjhvfjbfbghluh7l3slq0lukf112r6.apps.googleusercontent.com');
  $client->setAccessType('offline_access');

  $service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
  //show($service);
  
  
  // получаем количество уникальных посетителей конкретного профиля с 2009 года
    
    $data = $service->data_ga->get(
      'ga:314964844', '2009-01-01', date('Y-m-d'), 'ga:visitors', array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
      //'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/user/mihdan/',
    ));
    
  print_r($data);

?>
```

But I got error:

> [17-May-2022 04:06:33 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Google_ServiceException: Error calling GET
> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A314964844&start-date=2009-01-01&end-date=2022-05-17&metrics=ga%3Avisitors&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath:
> (403) User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. in
> /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/libs/google/io/Google_REST.php:66
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/libs/google/io/Google_REST.php(36):
> Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
> #1 /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/libs/google/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186):
> Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
> #2 /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/libs/google/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(59):
> Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
> #3 /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/google.php(43):
> Google_DataGaServiceResource->get('ga:314964844', '2009-01-01',
> '2022-05-17', 'ga:visitors', Array)
> #4 {main}   thrown in /home/r/rlyzhov/rlyzhov.beget.tech/public_html/dashboard/libs/google/io/Google_REST.php
> on line 66

What I doing wrong? I want to get some metrics to internal use. Please help.

Comment: Did you set redirect URI in Google API Console? If yes, is it the same as the one which you are using in code `'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/oauth2callback.php'`?

Comment: @dikesh I set same adressess in try_google.php, oauth2callback.php and at settings of my app in Google Console, then I did see authorization by choosing Google Account. But then I was redirected to the index.page of my site.How I can get ga data? I need to cuse simple query

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors here and they mean diffrent things.  The first error

> redirect_uri_mismatch

Means that the redirect uri that your applicaton is using is not one that is currently listed and configured in Google developer console.  The error message tells you exactly what needs to be added its.

```
http://romanlyzhov.ru/dashboard/oauth2callback.php
```

- [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

The second error message U`ser does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.`  Means exactly that.

The user you are currently authenticating with does not have access to the google analytics account you are requesting data from that being `ga:314964844`

Solution is to grant this user access or login with a user that does have access.

Comment: 1. I set same adressess in try_google.php, oauth2callback.php and at settings of my app in Google Console, then I did see authorization by choosing Google Account. But then I was redirected to the index.page of my site.How I can get ga data? I need to use simple query for metrics 'users', 'searchEngine' and something else. 2. I had add app account quickstart@riddlesbest.iam.gserviceaccount.com in Service accounts, add .p12 key file on server and write path to it. What I do wrong?